# eliminate '++' unary operator in antlr lexer

Tags: antlr, antlr3, lexer

I'm new to antlr3, and I'm trying to write a lexer that accept '+' and '-' as a special symbol but when see '++' operator it should treat it as a error but I don't know how to implement it, now with below specification it tokenize '++' as two token '+' and '+'.

```
SPECIALSYMBOL: ('+'|'-');
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep your `SPECIALSYMBOL` as it is and handle the case in the parser rules : if you do not allow repeated `SPECIALSYMBOL` in your rules, a `++` should produce an error.